# Converter RS232-Optical

Tags: converter, optical-fibre

Based on the configuration below:

[Network Element 1] ----(RS232 TX)----[Converter RS232-Optical]-------[Converter Optical-RS232]----(RS232 signal) ----> [Network Element 2]

From the network element 2 point of view, I need to know whether the network Element 1 is available and connected.

Would it be possible to invert the behavior of the converter RS232-Optical (and reciprocally the converter Optical(RS232), so that when no traffic RS 232 is received the optical signal is on ? Is there any RS232-optical converter acting like this ?

Based on this signal, I would know the availability of network element 1.

Thanks in advance for any light that you could share

D

Comment: Of course inverting something is possible in theory. If you are talking about using specific devices, we don't know which devices you mean and if it is possible with them.

Comment: Isn't this already the case? RS232 was designed 'inverted' so that you could detect a loss of signal (the 'break' signal is in fact done *asserting* the line, like it was physically disconnected). Try other kind of optical converters, the phylosophy behind *should* be exactly as you need. Some converters also have 'broken fiber' detection since they also send an idle signal.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio RS-232 being inverted has nothing to do with this. RS-232 uses positive and negative voltages, so if there is any voltage present there is something connected, if there is no voltage present then there is nothing connected.

Comment: Yes it's positive and negative but look at the failsafe behaviour of transceivers… it all goes back to current loop ('break' meaning, most importantly)

Comment: Thanks for your "optical" lights.  Do you know any reference of RS232-Optical converter acting like this: 1/ RS232 signal is up (no RS 232 data signal is transmitted) -> the optical fiber is lighted and 2/ RS232 signal is dow (RS232 signal is transmittedf) -> The optical fiber is unlighted

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Yes but with a break you can only detect if the optical link is broken or optical transmitter unpowered. There is no way to know if "network device 1" is powered down via standard RS-232 interface, even if the RS-232 to optical transceiver is up and running. Not unless if handshake signals are used, to know if the data set or data terminal signals ready.

Comment: RS-232 specifies some signal levels, and LOTS of auxiliary flags,  including RTS and such, that could be part of an optical link, or not.   There's too many ways to 'convert'.